# WPF TextBox - enable ValidationRule, TabIndex, & Paceholder/Text Hint

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a group of TextBox input fields using WPF.

**My wishlist**

I would like to apply all three features to the input fields. I can get each feature to work individually, but I run into issues when all three are configured.

1. Tab Order - have the ability to keyboard tab thru each field to input value
2. Validation Rule - On LostFocus, validate text is alphanumeric only
3. Placeholder - Add text placeholder/text hint to textbox. on focus, field is cleared. Style is different for placeholder vs user input

with below code, i can get tab index and my validation rule to work as expected, but when i add placeholder portion to my control template, validation rule does not trigger and Keyboard tab no longer works. But, my placeholder works great..... i remove the placeholder section and tab index / validation start working again.

**view.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="SurveyInputProject" TabIndex="0" Tag="Project Name" Style="{StaticResource SurveyInputText}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SurveyInput.Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validate:SurveyProjectValidate ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**style.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="SurveyInputText" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource cCharcoal}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SurveyTextBoxDefault}"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="Error" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="SurveyTextBoxDefault" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**To enable my placeholder**

- In my control template, i remove the ScrollView element and add the following Grid/TextBlock

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Opacity=".5" Foreground="{StaticResource cGray}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TexBoxPlaceholder}">
                <Binding ElementName="InputField" Path="Text.IsEmpty"/>
                <Binding ElementName="InputField" Path="IsFocused"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Visibility>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="InputField" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
</Grid>
```

Template Modified

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SurveyTextBoxDefault" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Opacity=".5" Foreground="{StaticResource cGray}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TexBoxPlaceholder}">
                    <Binding ElementName="InputField" Path="Text.IsEmpty"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="InputField" Path="IsFocused"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Visibility>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="InputField" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My guess is it is somewhere in my TextBlock and Focus values, but I cannot find the right combo to work. I also tried to remove textblock by moving the value converter for the placeholder to my view (textbox element) and use a multibind for both validation and placeholder, but i then get errors about no having my data binding (path) on the parent element.

Comment: its interesting could you share your complete source code? to have a sample to study..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ControlTemplate` is wrong. You can't add a `TextBox` into the template of a `TextBox`. This doesn't make sense either. The problem you are facing is that you are typing into the inner `TextBox`. This inner `TextBox` has not the desired tab index and it is not bound to any source and therefore not validating. The `ValidationRule` is actually applied to the outer `TextBox` (the templated parent).

The `TextBox` *requires* a text site element named `PART_ContentHost` (for example a `Border`). Elements that are found in templates and that are named with the `PART_` prefix can be considered as mandatory. Otherwise the templated control won't behave as intended.
Just put the `ScrollViewer` back (to replace the inner `TextBox`) and bind the placeholder `TextBlock` to the templated parent (the `TextBox` the template is applied to) using the `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` markup extension in your `MultiBinding`.

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SurveyTextBoxDefault"
                 TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Border x:Name="border"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <Grid>
      <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                 Margin="10,0,0,0"
                 Opacity=".5"
                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock.Visibility>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TexBoxPlaceholder}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                     Path="Text.IsEmpty" />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                     Path="IsFocused" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Visibility>
      </TextBlock>

      <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                    Focusable="false"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   ...
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Great Info. I have not used TemplateParent before. Thank you for the example and your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my placeholder.

1. removed placeholder config from my control template
2. wrapped my textbox in a grid with textblock element
3. created a new style for textblock with style triggers to toggle visibility on focus, text input, etc.

now all three features work as expected.

***view***

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="SurveyInputProject" TabIndex="0" Tag="Project Name" Style="{StaticResource SurveyInputText}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="SurveyInput.Name" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"        
                 Mode="TwoWay">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validate:SurveyProjectValidate ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SurveyInputPlaceholder}" Text="Project Name" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```

***style***

```
<Style x:Key="SurveyInputPlaceholder" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource cGray}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SurveyInput.Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SurveyInputProject, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=SurveyInputProject }" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution  to create a placeholder with adoner:

```
class TextBoxWithPlaceHolder.cs

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TextBoxWithPlaceHolderExample
{
    public class TextBoxWithPlaceHolder : TextBox
    {
        #region Properties
        public string Label
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Label.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxWithPlaceHolder), new UIPropertyMetadata("Label"));

        public Style LabelStyle
        {
            get { return (Style)GetValue(LabelStyleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelStyleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LabelStyle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelStyleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(TextBoxWithPlaceHolder), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        public bool HasText
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HasTextProperty); }
            private set { SetValue(HasTextPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasTextPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasText", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxWithPlaceHolder), new PropertyMetadata(false));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasTextProperty = HasTextPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        #endregion

        public TextBoxWithPlaceHolder()
            : base()
        {
        }

        AdornerLayer myAdornerLayer;
        AdornerLabel myAdornerLabel;
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            myAdornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
            myAdornerLabel = new AdornerLabel(this, Label, LabelStyle);
            UpdateAdorner(this);

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor focusProp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(FrameworkElement.IsFocusedProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement));
            if (focusProp != null)
            {
                focusProp.AddValueChanged(this, delegate
                {
                    UpdateAdorner(this);
                });
            }

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor containsTextProp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBoxWithPlaceHolder.HasTextProperty, typeof(TextBoxWithPlaceHolder));
            if (containsTextProp != null)
            {
                containsTextProp.AddValueChanged(this, delegate
                {
                    UpdateAdorner(this);
                });
            }
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            HasText = this.Text != "";

            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            myAdornerLayer.RemoveAdorners<AdornerLabel>(this); // requires AdornerExtensions.cs

            base.OnDragEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnDragLeave(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateAdorner(this);

            base.OnDragLeave(e);
        }

        private void UpdateAdorner(FrameworkElement elem)
        {
            if (((TextBoxWithPlaceHolder)elem).HasText || elem.IsFocused)
            {
                // Hide the Shadowed Label
                this.ToolTip = this.Label;
                myAdornerLayer.RemoveAdorners<AdornerLabel>(elem);  // requires AdornerExtensions.cs
            }
            else
            {
                // Show the Shadowed Label
                this.ToolTip = null;
                if (!myAdornerLayer.Contains<AdornerLabel>(elem))  // requires AdornerExtensions.cs
                    myAdornerLayer.Add(myAdornerLabel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

class AdornerLabel.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TextBoxWithPlaceHolderExample
{
    // Adorners must subclass the abstract base class Adorner.
    public class AdornerLabel : Adorner
    {
        private readonly TextBlock _textBlock;

        // Be sure to call the base class constructor.
        public AdornerLabel(UIElement adornedElement, string label, Style labelStyle)
            : base(adornedElement)
        {
            _textBlock = new TextBlock
            {
                Style = labelStyle,
                Text = label
            };
        }

        //make sure that the layout system knows of the element
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            _textBlock.Measure(constraint);
            return _textBlock.DesiredSize;
        }
        
        //make sure that the layout system knows of the element
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            _textBlock.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
            return finalSize;
        }

        //return the visual that we want to display
        protected override System.Windows.Media.Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return _textBlock;
        }

        //return the count of the visuals
        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

some AdornerExtension

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TextBoxWithPlaceHolderExample
{
    public static class AdornerExtensions
    {
        public static void RemoveAdorners<T>(this AdornerLayer adr, UIElement elem)
        {
            Adorner[] adorners = adr.GetAdorners(elem);

            if (adorners == null) return;

            for (int i = adorners.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (adorners[i] is T)
                    adr.Remove(adorners[i]);   
            }
        }

        public static bool Contains<T>(this AdornerLayer adr, UIElement elem)
        {
            Adorner[] adorners = adr.GetAdorners(elem);

            if (adorners == null) return false;

            for (int i = adorners.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (adorners[i] is T)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static void RemoveAll(this AdornerLayer adr, UIElement elem)
        {
            try
            {
                Adorner[] adorners = adr.GetAdorners(elem);

                if (adorners == null) return;

                foreach (Adorner toRemove in adorners)
                    adr.Remove(toRemove);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public static void RemoveAllRecursive(this AdornerLayer adr, UIElement element)
        {
            try
            {
                Action<UIElement> recurse = null;
                recurse = ((Action<UIElement>)delegate(UIElement elem)
                {
                    adr.RemoveAll(elem);
                    if (elem is Panel panel)
                    {
                        foreach (UIElement e in panel.Children)
                            recurse(e);
                    }
                    else if (elem is Decorator decorator)
                    {
                        recurse(decorator.Child);
                    }
                    else if (elem is ContentControl control)
                    {
                        if (control.Content is UIElement)
                            recurse(control.Content as UIElement);
                    }

                });

                recurse(element);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

---

how to use it: in xaml file

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxWithPlaceHolderExample.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxWithPlaceHolderExample"
    Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="700" Style="{StaticResource dataWindow}">
    <Window.Resources>
        
        <Style x:Key="PlaceHolderLabelStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Opacity" Value="0.8" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Margin" Value="8,4,4,4" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2,2,2" />
            <Setter Property="LabelStyle" Value="{StaticResource PlaceHolderLabelStyle}" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource dataBorder}">
        <Grid DataContext="{x:Static local:Customer.GetHomerSimpson}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="First Name" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="Middle Name" Text="{Binding MiddleName}" Grid.Column="1" />
                <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="Last Name" Text="{Binding LastName}" Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>

            <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="Job Title" Text="{Binding JobTitle}" Grid.Row="2" />

            <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="Company" Text="{Binding Company}" Grid.Row="3" />

            <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="Address1" Text="{Binding Address1}" Grid.Row="5" />

            <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="Address2" Text="{Binding Address2}" Grid.Row="6" />

            <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="City" Text="{Binding City}" />
                <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="State" Text="{Binding State}" Grid.Column="1" />
                <local:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder Label="Zip" Text="{Binding Zip}" Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

---

one good thing i see with this method is to simplify the way to add the placeholder and the simplification of the style used

Result:

[image]